# What is wrong with this database code - keep getting errors saying near line 15 and near line 25

Tags: database

```
.echo on
.mode column 
.headers on


PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

.open ComputerGames.db

DROP TABLE games;
DROP TABLE publishers;
```

from the line create table games and create table publishers there are errors

```
CREATE TABLE games (
  gameID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  gameName (20)TEXT NOT NULL CHECK ,
  publisherName(20) TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (publisherName in ("Rockstar", 
  "Bethesda","Valve","Superhot team", "Mojang", "Epic games", "Bungie","Nintendo")) REFERENCES 
  publishers (publisherName),
  gameReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
  gameGenre (10) TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (gameGenre in ("RPG","Simulation","Shooter","Sports")),
  gameAgeRating NUMBER NOT NULL CHECK (gameAgeRating in(3,7,12,15,18)),
  gameRRP MONEY NOT NULL CHECK (gameRRP >= 0)
  );

 CREATE TABLE publishers (
  publisherName (20) TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  publisherFounded DATE NOT NULL,
  publisherCountry (15) TEXT NOT NULL,
  publisherCity (15) TEXT NOT NULL, 
  publisherPhone (15) TEXT,
  publisherWeb (25)
  );
```

not really sure why this is happening or what the errors are

Comment: What's the specific error?

Comment: When a table references another one, you should create the other one first. This is the case with `publishers` that should be created before than `games`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE publishers (
publisherName TEXT(20)  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
publisherFounded DATE NOT NULL,
publisherCountry TEXT(15)  NOT NULL,
publisherCity TEXT(15)  NOT NULL, 
publisherPhone TEXT(15),
publisherWeb TEXT(25)
);


CREATE TABLE games (
gameID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
gameName TEXT(20) NOT NULL,
publisherName TEXT(20) NOT NULL CHECK (
publisherName IN (
  "Rockstar",
  "Bethesda",
  "Valve",
  "Superhot team",
  "Mojang",
  "Epic games",
  "Bungie",
  "Nintendo"
)
) REFERENCES publishers (publisherName),
gameReleaseDate DATE NOT NULL,
gameGenre TEXT(10) NOT NULL CHECK (
gameGenre IN ("RPG", "Simulation", "Shooter", "Sports")),
gameAgeRating NUMBER NOT NULL CHECK (gameAgeRating IN(3, 7, 12, 15, 18)),
gameRRP MONEY NOT NULL CHECK (gameRRP >= 0)
);
```

Its pointing syntax error which you have to declare datatype and length beside declaration, compare this code to yours you'll get,I think this will work now